# How to change Bootstrap 3 list icon while collapse and expand

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, thymeleaf

I have list with sub menu's and I can't achieve the change of icon when the content is collapsing and expanding.

```
<!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
    <aside class="main-sidebar">
        <!-- sidebar: style can be found in sidebar.less -->
        <section class="sidebar">
        <ul class="sidebar-menu">
                <li th:class="${CURRENT_MENU == 'Users' || CURRENT_MENU == 'Roles'}? 'active' : 'null'"
                    sec:authorize="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USERS','ROLE_ROLES')"
                    class="treeview" id="scrollspy-components"><a
                    href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-user-circle-o"></i>
                        <span>User Management</span></a>
                    <ul class="nav treeview-menu">
                        <li th:class="${CURRENT_MENU == 'Users'}? 'active' : ''"
                            sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USERS')"><a
                            href="#" th:href="@{'/users'}"> <i class="fa fa-users"></i><span>
                                    Users</span></a></li>

                        <li th:class="${CURRENT_MENU == 'Roles'}? 'active' : ''"
                            sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ROLES')"><a
                            href="#" th:href="@{'/roles'}"> <i class="fa fa-tag"></i><span>
                                    Roles</span></a></li>

                    </ul>
                </li>
        </ul>
        </section>
    </aside>
```